# How to get functions.php to talk to options.php

Tags: theme-options

I am using [Options Framework](http://wptheming.com/options-framework-theme/) to build a list of theme options (using code from the theme, not the plugin).

I have a colour picker as an option, and I can set and call this colour okay.

I'd like to convert the RGB value to HSV, and I found the code to do that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3597417/php-hsv-to-rgb-formula-comprehension).

I entered this code into my functions.php, in a function called [convert_RGA_HSV (on pastebin)](http://pastebin.com/XdSyyWxY).  It accepts a RGB colour, and returns an array($H, $S, $V).

Also in functions.php I have:

```
function set_HSV () {
    $varcolour = of_get_option('custom_colour');
    $varhsv = convert_RGA_HSV($varcolour);
    add_option( 'hsv', $varhsv, '', 'yes' );
}

add_action( 'after_setup_theme', 'set_HSV' );
```

of_get_option is the function built into the Options Framework to return a value of an option.

I don't know if this set_HSV function is being run, or if it is not working properly, **as no option called hsv is being inserted into theme options**.

Comment: have you enabled debugging to see if any errors are produced? how are you accessing the value of the `hsv` option in your code?

Comment: Is `$varcolour = of_get_option('custom_colour');` actually set before you are trying to retrieve it?

Comment: @userabuser Yes, of_get_option('custom_colour') will already return a value.

Comment: Is your function `convert_RGA_HSV` accessible to your `set_HSV` function? Check by dumping the `$varhsv` variable. If you don't need `add_option`'s extra parameters then its also OK to use `update_option` which will create the option if it does not exist and or update the option if it already exists. Syntax: `update_option( $option, $new_value );`

Comment: @Steve - you didn't say how you were attempting to access the `hsv` option, `of_get_option('hsv')` will not work, as it's not part of your array of theme options, you've saved it under its own key so you have to use WordPress' `get_option`

Comment: @Milo; you're right.  I now use get_option, but the output just shows "Array".  How do output a 3 value array using get_option?  BTW; get_option($h), get_option($s), get_option($v) all work; just not the array get_option($hsv).

Comment: @Steve - see answer below

Answer (score 1):

When you save an array of data in an option, WordPress serializes it to save, then when you use get_option, it gets unserialized back into the original array, so it can be accessed as you'd access any indexed array without keys in php:

original option added:

```
$hsv = array('hval','sval','vval');
add_option('hsv', $hsv);
```

then, to access this data:

```
$hsv = get_option('hsv');
echo 'h value is ' . $hsv[0];
echo 's value is ' . $hsv[1];
echo 'v value is ' . $hsv[2];
```